# Get custom configuration .cs file path in a class library project that is being referenced by a console application

Tags: c#, class-library

I have a class library created with dot net core 3.1. There are two files which I am using for logging and reading appsetting.json file.
For this I am using two custom class files  respectively for logging and reading appesttings.json file.
Here is sample code for same.

1)Logging (File 1:CustomLogger.cs)

[image: reading log4net settings]

2)Reading appsetting.json (File 2: ConfigHelper.cs)

[image]

Now I am consuming my class library by adding project reference in another separate console application.

When I run my console application, I am getting an exception in GetCurrentSettings method where I am not able to reach to appsetting.json file. Instead it is trying to find that file in current console application of bin folder.

So How could I read appsetting.json values from base project.

Comment: Don't put your code as images next time, it's difficult read to others

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi :Due to security reasons I am unable to copy code. But I will avoid using images next time. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: does your problem resolve? then please mark any answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the appsettings SHOULD be copied to the bin folder as part of the build.

`appsettings.X.json` should have a setting:

> Copy to output directory: "Copy if newer"

Comment: I did as per your suggestion. But I got different error. So I modified code as below in base project. Where it is trying to find a appsettings.json file in bin folder of console application and its not present there so its throwing an error.

Comment: modified code as like : Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the `appsettings.json` file and set the Copy to output directory value as **Copy if never** or **Copy always**

[image]